# add a discount filter in layered navigation in Prestashop 1.6.*

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I want to add discount filters like:

```
[]20%-30%
[]30%-40%
```

in the category page of my site. Any way to achieve the same? There doesn't seem to be much support regarding the issue out there.

Comment: so, I've got this module in my shop that displays discount enabled prices on products on category pages. so far I haven't yet tried anything as I need an idea to be able to get started. I know a little bit of programming, but need a starting point. thanks for taking time and commenting.

Comment: It might not be easy. The module responsible for the filters is called `blocklayered`. You will have to override parts of it to be able to display your discounts, and also override the SQL parts so as the click on one of the discount ranges actually filters the category list.

Comment: thanks, again, for taking the time. i guess for now i'm gonna try out the option Aurora suggests in the answer section. it's not really the solution i was looking for but could work on a temporary basis.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this (without any programming) is to create new features and link those to your product(s) which have a discount (like 20%-30% off, 30%-40% off, etc.). After you have done this, add those in the config of the blocklayered module so people can filter on products which have a discount.

Comment: Saves you a lot of time and trouble ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm finally going to do (thanks to @Aurora and @Julien Lachal):

1. I'm going to create new features and have it attributes like 20%-30%, 30%-40%, so on. Now, I'm not gonna go through each products which has discount enabled and assign them these features. Instead,
2. I'm gonna do a little modification to the discount module to assign these features for me.
3. As and when the discount module's core class is going to assign discount to my selected products, I'm gonna have it to call addFeaturesToDB(arrayFeatures()), which is productcore function, to the same products.
   Thanks.